# Git clone error [warning] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../.git/refs/remotes/origin/main'

Tags: git, github, github-actions, vscode-extensions

MacOS VSCode clone project from git

I Try to clone git repository, after clone, git remand

> [warning] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/username/GitHub/project_name/.git/refs/remotes/origin/main'

I found the main file in /.git/refs/heads/main, the 'origin' folder only have 'HEAD'file.

I tried to copy the 'main'file to the 'origin' folder, it didn't work.

How can I solve this :(

[Origin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fitaE.png)

Comment: Don't make any changes in .git. Your local repository is already broken. You now should git clone it again.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you shouldn't need to go directly into the .git folder, unless you're doing advanced things like git hooks.

Did you get the error when the `git clone` command itself was running? Or was it later when trying to do something else? If it was something else, you might want to add more details to your question about what you're trying to do.